# Delete an SObject by knowing only Id

Tags: contact, sobject, dml, delete, id

Is it possible to delete an SObject by knowing only Id?

[Here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008wUnIAI) is what I found:

```
Id del = '003S00000099999'; // whatever ID you are deleting 
Contact ct = new Contact(Id = del); 
delete ct;
```

So, is it safe to always use a standard object like the Contact or maybe Account to delete records by knowing only Id? Or are there better ways of accomplishing this?

Just checked. The approach of using Contact does not work.

Comment: What do you mean by "[it] does not work"? That approach works fine provided you have the right kind of sObject for that Id.

Comment: You can delete record this way. Any delete triggers are being run as well in this case, and any lookups that restrict deletion are also taken into account.

Comment: @DavidReed, I have only `Id` and I do not guarantee the type of object.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can delete an object knowing only its Id.

If you know the object's type at development time, you can initialize an sObject instance with the Id and supply it to the `delete` DML operator, as you show:

```
Contact ct = new Contact(Id = del); 
delete ct;
```

If you don't know the object's type, you can pass the Id directly to `Database.delete()`, which as you noted has an overloaded variant that takes a record Id directly. You can also, if you do not know the Id's type at compile time, construct an sObject instance dynamically at runtime, which you can then pass to any and all `Database` methods and DML operations:

```
Account a = new Account(Name = 'Account');
insert a;

Id i = a.Id;
sObject q = i.getSobjectType().newSobject(i);
delete q;
```

Comment: The last option is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can delete the record by using only Id. Ideally it is not a good way to delete for major records. But you can restrict the deletion at profile level in object permissions. Instead of deleting records directly you can use multiple criteria and delete record.

Comment: It seems that `Database.delete(myRecordId);` is the best way to go here.

Comment: Could you expand on your answer to explain what you mean by "it is not a good way to delete" and "use multiple criteria and delete record"?